# DropDownList: SelectedIndexChanged do not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fill a ASP Dropdownlist in the pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {           
                for (int i = 0; i < _maxStationsAnz; i++)
                {
                    String stations = arrayList[1];

                    _allData = stations.Split(Convert.ToChar("/"));
                    _data = _allData[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(";"));

                    ddWeatherstations.Items.Add(_data[0]);
                }
        }
```

When a new station is selected, it should update informations. I use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` attribute on my aspx site.

My code behind:

```
protected void ddWeatherstations_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _maxStationsAnz; i++)
        {
            if (ddWeatherstations.SelectedIndex == i)
            {
                  lselected.Text = "Index changed!";
                  //unimportant code
                  //....
            }
        }
    }
```

When I set a breakpoint and run the program and change the value of the dropdownlist, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `AutoPostBack` property of your dropdownlist `ddWeatherstations` to `True`.

Try This:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddWeatherstations" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddWeatherstations_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property `AutoPostBack="true"` but this will post back all of your page every time you select a different index of your DropDownList so I will suggest you to put your DropDownList in an AJAX Update Panel.